# Issues setting up MXChip, VSCode, Arduino, MX3166 environment on MAC

Tags: iot-devkit

Error Presented: #include errors detected. Please update your includePath. IntelliSense features for this translation unit(/Users/x/Documents/Arduino/generated_examples/GetStarted_3/GetStarted.ino)will be provided by the Tag Parser.

For example, the following files are not found:

```
#include "AZ3166WiFi.h"
#include "AzureIotHub.h"
#include "DevKitMQTTClient.h"
```

What have I done:
Arduino is installed (and runs), Arduino is added to the path as /Applications in the UserSettings.pref. DevKit was installed, pretty much everything works, except this intellisense/libraries location problem.

Answer (score 2):

Actually this is an issue coming from the [Microsoft C/C++ extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools).

Here is the solution to fix this issue:

1. Press F1 and key in 'settings' and select the **Preferences: Open User Settings**

   [image: User settings]

   then add this setting to your user settings

   [image: Set C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine]
2. Press F1 and key in 'cpp' and select the **C/Cpp: Edit Configurations...**

   [image: C/Cpp: Edit Configurations]

   this will open / create the c_cpp_properties.json file, add the path of Arduino package into the include path:

   [image: Add the AZ3166 SDK path]

You can get more detail from [C/C++ for VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp).

Answer (score 0):

Although it might seems to work better with Tag Parser, I believe it's not the solution, and actually it should default to Tag Parser.

Comments in Default Settings, C/C++ section say:

> // Controls the IntelliSense provider. "Tag Parser" provides "fuzzy"
>   results that are not context-aware. "Default" provides context-aware
>   results and is in preview mode - member list, hover tooltips, and
>   error squiggles are currently implemented. Features not yet
>   implemented in the new default engine will use the tag parser engine
>   instead.   "C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Default",
>
> // Controls whether the IntelliSense engine will automatically
>   switch to the Tag Parser for translation units containing #include
>   errors.   "C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngineFallback": "Enabled",